# check if there is element on X,Y position on the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, screen

There is anyway to check if there is element on X,Y position on website screen?
for example: check if there is banner/image on website on position top: 0; left: 0;

Comment: @Teemu how can i create a range selection? for element that are between y=0 to y=120?

Comment: That's a different question, but [`Range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range) and [`Selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) ; ).

Comment: @user3519234 does my answer help you? are you looking for a jQuery solution, or pure JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's "position":

Given element: `<span id="el"></span>`

JavaScript:

```
var el = $("#el").position(),
    x = el.left, 
    y = el.top;
$("#el").append("("+ x + " , " + y + ")");
```

[image]

JS BIN: http://jsbin.com/lujoxoladi/1/edit?html,css,js,output